# Use multiple files in ffmpeg slideshow as input without glob

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a slideshow with ffmpeg using a directory of images. On Linux, I can just use `-pattern_type=glob` but on flutter_ffmpeg (ffmpeg for Flutter apps), glob is not supported. The images are not sequential, they are date formatted like this:

```
2020-04-09T14:16:52.png 2020-04-09T14:18:53.png 2020-04-09T14:20:54.png 2020-04-09T14:22:55.png 2020-04-09T14:24:56.png 2020-04-09T14:26:57.png 2020-04-09T14:28:58.png 2020-04-09T14:30:59.png 2020-04-09T14:33:00.png 2020-04-09T14:35:01.png 
2020-04-09T14:17:53.png 2020-04-09T14:19:54.png 2020-04-09T14:21:55.png 2020-04-09T14:23:56.png 2020-04-09T14:25:57.png 2020-04-09T14:27:58.png 2020-04-09T14:29:59.png 2020-04-09T14:32:00.png 2020-04-09T14:34:01.png 2020-04-09T14:36:02.png
```

If I use each image as an input like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 2020-04-09T14:30:59.png -i 2020-04-09T14:27:58.png -i 2020-04-09T14:28:58.png output.mp4
```

output.mp4 is overwritten every time and only contains one image.

How can I use all the files without using glob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename them in sequential order or use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).

1. Make `input.txt`:

   ```
   file '2020-04-09T14:16:52.png'
   duration 5
   file '2020-04-09T14:18:53.png'
   duration 5
   file '2020-04-09T14:20:54.png'
   duration 5
   ```
2. Run `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf format=yuv420 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).